# How to create a video blog with Django?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django. I have started with Django girls blog tutorial which is very basic. Now I want to convert this with the conceptual video blog where user can upload a video like Youtube and user will be able to play that video on the page blog. Besides, I want every post will be moderated by admin. Can anyone expert help me with some coding suggestion as I am newcomer? I have included the completed code bellow.

```
#ALL MODELS

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

###############################################################

# ALL VIEWS
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import PostForm


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
            published_date__lte=timezone.now(
            )).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
           # post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})



def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            # post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

###################################################################
# URL patterns 

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]

#################################################################
# Forms 

from django import forms

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

Comment: You may find this questions gets closed, as discussions on matters of opinion like this can run on for ever without reaching any useful conclusions. It isn't personal. You may find [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helpful in formulating questions.

Comment: @holdenweb Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to provide code but failed for indentation problem. I could not fix this, that's why I have avoided the sample code. Can I add them now?

Comment: It'd be better to post a new question, with appropriately indented code snippets.

Comment: Guys, now I have edited my question. I hope this will better reflect my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have solved my problem on my own. I have added just a simple code inside the video tag of html5. I have provided the code bellow.

**Code for model:**

```
from django.db import models

class VideoUploader(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    clip = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**HTML5 post list page:**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="post">               
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <video src="{{ post.clip.url }}" controls controlsList="nodownload" 
    width="640" height="480"></video>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```